# Apache access log meaning

Tags: apache, access-log

I'm trying to understand my access log. I didn't find any format example like this.

```
2162004 93.186.15.149   [25/Apr/2016:12:53:40 +0200]    4914163 200 www.example.org "GET /foto/376.JPG HTTP/1.1"
```

I don't get the first long number before the IP and the second long number before the 200 status.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

First long should be Bytes sent and the second one is Time spent(ms)

But you need to confirm that with your log format under httpd.conf to understand the meaning of each value.
Help yourself with this to better understand your log:
list:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html